# Enabling modules my site has been partially crashed?

Tags: database

When I enabled some modules (Drupal Chat, Chat room, and Node.js) my site crashed, and it reported some errors; I have removed my modules entirely, and reloaded the site, but still the errors are showing on the dashboard.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]:  Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try  restarting transaction: DELETE FROM {semaphore}  WHERE  (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (value =  :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array (     [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => menu_rebuild     [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =>  20854936424f460742220126.19788787 )  in `lock_release()` (line 254 of /var/www/mute/includes/lock.inc

How can I fix this?

Comment: Fix can be found in here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/115469/314

Answer (score 0):

My guess from the general content of the message is that something went wrong while those modules were installing relating to database modifications.  If you were making backups of the database, you should revert. Or are you saying that you did revert and still have the problem?  If so, I am at a bit of a loss to know why. It could be a problem with the database engine and you may want to backup your current database, reinstall your database software, and restore your database.

Remember,  if you installed these modules by simply copying the modules into the directory, you should run the command 'update.php' on the URL to insure that the database is configured correctly and Drupal is getting the correct information about the database and the status of all the modules.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the help.. but what you said i had done it still the problem didn't resolved...........